# According to LDS teaching, was Adam the first man created in all the worlds or just this one?

Tags: lds, creation, adam

In Moses 1:34, we read the following:

> And the first man of all men have I called Adam, which is many.  (Moses 1:34)

According to LDS teaching, God made many worlds through His Son Jesus.  We are informed here that God called the first man by the name of Adam.

Was this the first man created on all the worlds created by God or just the first man on this particular world?

Was Adam the first son of God in the pre-mortal life as well?  If so, did this distinction carry through to the honor of being the first man in this world or could this have been for another reason?  If not, was there another distinction in the pre-mortal life that resulted in him being selected to be the first man on this world?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer can actually be found in the very next verse:

> 35 But only an account of this earth, and the inhabitants thereof, give I unto you. **For behold, there are many worlds that have passed away by the word of my power.** And there are many that now stand, and innumerable are they unto man; but all things are numbered unto me, for they are mine and I know them.

If many worlds had already existed and completed their cycle by this point, then clearly Adam was the first man of this world.

He was definitely chosen for a reason, out of all the spirit children of God who were to come to this earth, to hold a preeminent place in creation.  Exactly what that reason was has not been revealed, though there are three passages in the Doctrine and Covenants that refer to Adam as being the same person as Michael the Archangel.  (See [D&C 27:11](http://www.lds.org/scriptures/dc-testament/dc/27.11?lang=eng#10), [107:54](http://www.lds.org/scriptures/dc-testament/dc/107.54?lang=eng#53), and [128:21](http://www.lds.org/scriptures/dc-testament/dc/128.21?lang=eng#20).)

Comment: The presence of many worlds does not necessitate that there were any living creatures, or any children of God, on those worlds.

Comment: @Jeff But this does: [D&C 76:24](http://www.lds.org/scriptures/dc-testament/dc/76.24?lang=eng#23)

Answer (score 0):

As for your question that was not answered.
Was Adam the first son of God in the pre-mortal life as well?

Jesus is the firstborn of the spirit children of our Heavenly Father, the Only Begotten of the Father in the flesh, and the first to rise from the dead in the Resurrection, “that in all things he might have the preeminence” (Col. 1:13–18).